# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)

Tags: java, android

can anyone help me solve this problem I don't understand what exactly is wrong when I click on activity my app crashing I have already assigned the button still log showing me below error? I am unable to find the exception here. I tried by changing the id of a button. Then also, it didn't work. In XML file, Button is included.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.niyanta.askforleave/com.example.niyanta.askforleave.Activity.EmployeeLeave}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2911)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.niyanta.askforleave.Activity.EmployeeLeave.onCreate(EmployeeLeave.java:88)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7026)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7017)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1231)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
```

Here is my java code.....

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_leave);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ImageView ivBack = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ivBack);

    ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.employee_leave_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    Employeeleavelist = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!isConnectd(getApplicationContext())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        Log.e("LOGIN", "CALL API");
        getemployeelist();
    }

    btnApprove =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnApprove) ;
    btnApprove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            approved();
        }
    });



    btnReject =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReject);

}
```

here is my XML code :

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnApprove"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button3"
                    android:text="Approve"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"></LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnReject"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button2"
                    android:text="Reject"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:onClick="ShowDialog"/>
```

Comment: in which line you are getting exception

Comment: this one "btnApprove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {"

Comment: maybe you need to check the id of that button. ?

Comment: then check the id . Your btnApprove is null

Comment: you might be taking wrong id for buttonApprove provided in xml

Comment: clean the project and rebuild project. Make sure in xml file name of button is same as in java code.

Comment: see I added my XML code too, there is the same id in both code still I am getting this error.

Comment: Is that XML from `activity_employee_leave`?

Comment: `here is my XML code :` Of which file exactly?

Comment: maybe there is something wrong here too:
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ImageView ivBack = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ivBack);

Comment: Is this the complete xml code ? if not please post it

Comment: I have made two XML  1. contain Recyclerview   2. contain all the fields and this button is in second XMl

Comment: Your mistake is here `ImageView ivBack = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ivBack);`  Use (ImageView) instead of toolbar

Comment: I have used this in every activity but only this activity is giving me an error @SandeepParish

Comment: If `btnApprove` is not in `activity_employee_leave`, then `findViewById(R.id.btnApprove)` will return null. If you're saying that that `Button` is in the `RecyclerView`'s item layout, then you need to be finding it and setting it up in the `Adapter`, not in the `Activity`.

Comment: You finding id from toolbar find it from your layout and typecast with ImageView try and check if problem contentious then comment here

Comment: post the code of toolbar and ImageView xml

Comment: `ImageView ivBack = (ImageView).findViewById(R.id.ivBack);`  Replace it with yours

Comment: there is no `ivBack` in your XML

Comment: Thanks, I got my solution@MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

it's an `ImageView` not `toolbar` , You typecast it by `Toolbar` Object. Remove Toolbar Object from here.

```
ImageView ivBack = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ivBack);
```

And replace:

`ImageView ivBack = (ImageView).findViewById(R.id.ivBack);`

Comment: How does that solve the Exception that's being thrown by a `setOnClickListener()` call on a null `Button`?

Comment: You created object of `ImageView` and you typecast it by `toolbar` object so it showing Exception

Comment: Did you read the stack trace? That's not even close to what it shows is the issue. Anyway, that's not casting. That's a method call. Your suggested solution won't even compile.

Comment: `ivBack = (ImageView).findViewById(R.id.ivBack);` It's called TypeCasting not method call.

Comment: error is not related to `ClassCastException` it's related to `NullPointerException`, check the stacktrace posted

Comment: Not when you've got the dot operator there, like in the OP's code. They're calling `findViewById()` on `toolbar`. They aren't casting anything. Put your suggested solution into your IDE. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the coding of `approved()` because what this error means is that nothing is getting parsed through or parsing a null value which gives the error, so if you could update your question to show us the `approved()` coding then we can help

Answer (score 0):

check the findViewById return value, it may be null.

```
/**
 * Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that
 * was processed in {@link #onCreate}.
 *
 * @return The view if found or null otherwise.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("TypeParameterUnusedInFormals")
@Nullable
public abstract <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id);
```